# Invalid value style ((String)) for font -> style in Flutter

Tags: flutter, custom-font

For adding custom font style in pubspec.yaml gives

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Invalid value Bold ((String)) for font -> style.
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at /Users/directory/pubspec.yaml
```

here is the code in pubspec.yaml

```
  fonts:
    - family: Gilroy
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/gilroy_bold.ttf
          style: Bold
        - asset: fonts/gilroy_bolditalic.ttf
          weight: 900
        - asset: fonts/gilroy_medium.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Comment: Bold is not a style. Bold is a shortcut for weight value.

Comment: if you look at this doc then you'll see flutter.dev suggest to add style in this way https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts#2-declare-the-font-in-the-pubspec

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontWeight-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontStyle-class.html

Answer (score 5):

You want this.

```yaml
  fonts:
    - family: Gilroy
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/gilroy_bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/gilroy_bolditalic.ttf
          weight: 700
          style: italic
        - asset: fonts/gilroy_medium.ttf
          weight: 500
```

Comment: This is not possible Bold is no longer written.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `style: bold` does not work is because there is only two constants in [Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/index.html) > [dart:ui](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html) > [FontStyle enum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontStyle.html), which are:

- **italic** → `const FontStyle`
- **normal** → `const FontStyle`
- **values** → `const List<FontStyle>`

Check:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontStyle.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    fonts:
        - family: Gilroy
          fonts:
            - asset: fonts/gilroy_bold.ttf
              weight: <your_desired_value>  (But must be between 100 to 900)
            - asset: fonts/gilroy_bolditalic.ttf
              weight: 900
            - asset: fonts/gilroy_medium.ttf
              weight: 700
```